# How to mix strings in Python

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to write a function to mix strings in python but I am getting stuck at the end. So for this example, I have 2 words, mix and pod. I would like to create a function that returns: pox mid

My code only returns pox mix

Code:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
    if len(a and b)>1:
        b=str.replace(b,b[2],a[2:3])
        a=str.replace(a,a[2],b[2])
        print b,"",a
    return
mix_up('mix','pod')
```

I am seeking to do this for multiple words. So another example:

if I used dog,dinner

The output should return dig donner

Thanks!

Comment: This is not mixing...this is re-arranging to a specific pattern i.e. pod (the 2nd word), space, and the first word....I thought mixing would be something that you cannot say where pod and where mix will be placed....

Comment: Would you like to only swap the last letters of the two words? `mix` and `pod` become `mid` and `pox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little play on [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

```
def mix_up(first, second):
    new_first = second[:2] + first[2:]
    new_second = first[:2] + second[2:]
    return " ".join((new_first, new_second))

assert mix_up('mix','pod') == 'pox mid'
assert mix_up('dog','dinner') == 'dig donner'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanted to put the 2nd word before the first word all the time:

```
def mix_up(a,b):
    return " ".join([b,a])   # Should return pod mix
```

Give that you aimed for `pox mix` suggests that you probably wanted to:

1) Replace the last character of word `b` with x
2) Place b before a.

In that case, the function would be:

```
 def mix_up(a,b):
    b = b.replace(b[len(b)-1], 'x') # 'x' could be any other character
    return " ".join([b,a])   # Should return pox mix
```

you can simply swap b with a in order to change the position of the words.

If you didn't want the space in metween:

```
return "".join([b,a])
```

**UPDATE**

to "swap" the second letter between b and a, I simply correct your function like the following:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
    if len(a and b)>1:
        temp = b[1] # Store it in a temp
        b=str.replace(b,b[2],a[2:3])
        a=str.replace(a,a[2],b[2])
        print (b,"",a)
    return
mix_up('mix','pod')
```

Your only problem was once you replaced `b`, you were using the **new** `b` to chose the 2nd letter and replace into `a`.

Comment: In his example output OP swapped the last characters of the two words too

Comment: @mattm          I will update my answer once OP has demistified his question.....based on what he attempted to do...the solution above works...

Comment: @ha9u63ar, sorry should have been more clear. While this techincally solves this instance, it doesn't if I change the words. So if I use the words 
dog,dinner
the function should return dig donner

Answer (score 0):

```js
def mix_up(a, b):
  if len(a) < 2 or len(b) < 2: return
  return (b[:2] + a[2:] + " " + a[:2] + b[2:])
```